# Can Indian citizen travel to India from Australia with passport expiring in 3 months?

Tags: international-travel

I am living in Australia. I am an Indian citizen and my Indian passport is set to expire on 22nd September 2022. I am planning to travel to India in June 2022. Is it valid for me to travel to India or there is any six month passport validity rule?

Comment: Wait, you are travelling back to Australia afterwards ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can travel to India on an Indian passport with less than 6 months validity. Six-month validity rules apply when entering foreign countries, not your own home country, and not all countries have that requirement.